# Install error with lerna and yarn workspace

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg, lerna, yarn-workspaces

I implemented Lerna and yarn workspaces in my project and when I gonna install packages, it says

```
error Couldn't find package "@kratos/core@^1.0.1" required by "@kratos/storybook@1.0.1" on the "npm" registry.
```

Whereas these `@kratos/core` and `@kratos/storybook` packages exist in the packages folder and they are local packages.

I tried these commands but facing the below error:

- lerna add @kratos/core --scope @kratos/renderer:
- lerna add @kratos/core packages/renderer

```
lerna notice cli v3.22.0
lerna info versioning independent
lerna notice filter including "@kratos/renderer"
lerna info filter [ '@kratos/renderer' ]
lerna WARN No packages found where @kratos/core can be added.
```

Lerna config file:

```
{
    "useWorkspaces": true,
    "npmClient": "yarn",
    "packages": ["packages/*"],
    "version": "independent",
    "command": {
        "publish": {
            "ignoreChanges": [
                "test/**/*",
                "*.test.*",
                "*.spec.*",
                "cypress",
                "*.md",
                "scripts",
                "lib",
                "tslint.json",
                "tsconfig.json"
            ]
        },
        "run": {
            "npmClient": "yarn"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks, Lerna for having a lot of problems without useful documentation.

Comment: The first command you've tried seems to be right, check your package.json files, maybe it was already declared. You can also try adding using `yarn workspaces <workspace> add <package>` and see the logs, that's what Lerna is running internally.

Comment: it might help to also see the content of each `package.json`, since it's not clear if named them as `"@kratos/renderer"` or not and also how are you linking them in your dependencies list?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue but it was caused by something else. In my scenario, I was trying to link a package like so:

```
// package B

"dependencies": {
  "@scope/packageA": "*",
}
```

but Package A had a package.json with version specified as "0.x.0-alpha.1" which was causing Lerna to return a similar error:

> "error Couldn't find any versions for "@scope/packageA" that matches "*""

**Solution:**
Package A for us turned out to not be published to our NPM registry under any non-pre-release version. So, the solution was to revert the version string of Package A to be just, "0.x.0" (removed "-alpha.1" prefix) and then re-ran the `lerna bootstrap` command, and it worked!

Hope this helps :)

Comment: side note, you could use `workspace:*` which is similar to what you're trying to do, the [`workspace:`](https://pnpm.io/workspaces#workspace-protocol-workspace) is available with pnpm and yarn (not npm though)

Comment: This solve my issue, but is not the same from OP, but solve in my case. 
I'm create a pre-release version from one of my packages.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to run `lerna bootstrap` in order for lerna to create symbolic links for all of your `packages/*` in node_modules.
2. If your local version of any of your packages, in your case `@kratos/core`, does not match the version you are referencing in your package.json files, then it will try to import the package from npm. This could be why you are seeing "could not find package on the npm registry"

Comment: The number 1 should be removed, `lerna bootstrap` will be deprecated eventually and is not at all required with Yarn Workspaces, when using `useWorkspaces`, in which Yarn will create and handle all the symlinks and will probably overwrite anything that `bootstrap` might have created. The `boostrap` command is not at all included in [Lerna-Lite](https://github.com/ghiscoding/lerna-lite) fork and there are plenty of projects using Yarn Workspace with it. The number 2. seems valid and perhaps also add that the package name must match the one referenced in the dependencies as well